# Error converting YAML to JSON: did not find expected key - error in pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am getting the below error in my deployment pipeline

```
Error: YAML parse error on cnhsst/templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 38: did not find expected key
```

The yml file corresponding to this error is below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
      release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
  # We dont need a large deployment history limit as Helm keeps it's own
  # history
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
      labels:
        app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
        release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
      annotations:
        recreatePods: {{ randAlphaNum 8 | quote }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
        image: {{ template "docker-image" . }}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        # The port that our container listens for HTTP requests on
        - containerPort: {{ default 8000 .Values.portOverride }}
          name: http
        
      {{- if .Values.resources }}
        resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 10 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if and (.Values.livenessProbe) (.Values.apipod)}}
        livenessProbe:
{{ toYaml .Values.livenessProbe | indent 10 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if and (.Values.readinessProbe) (.Values.apipod)}}
        readinessProbe:
{{ toYaml .Values.readinessProbe | indent 10 }}
      {{- end }}
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
       securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 5000
        runAsGroup: 5000 
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - {{ template "fullname" . }}
              topologyKey: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
```

I am stuck with this issue for few hours. I have gone through numerous posts, tried online tools trying to figure out syntax errors, but unfortunately no luck. If anyone is able to point out the issue, that would be really great.

Comment: Just a shoot in the dark: there is the only empty line 37. Could this empty line be a cause of the error?

Comment: I tried removing this empty line, but it still shows the same error while checking it in http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: I'm not expert in YAML. Are you sure that yamllint.com is compatible with kubernetes-helm? I'm tried to paste in the linter some examples from helm docs: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/ and this linter trows errors almost always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the mismatched indentation under `regcred`:

```yaml
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      # <-- indented "-"
      #VVV not indented
       securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
```

which, as luck would have it, is the 38th line in the output YAML

```
$ helm template --debug my-chart . 2>&1| sed -e '1,/^apiVersion:/d' | sed -ne 38p
       securityContext:
```